# Paypal micropayments settings

Tags: paypal, settings

Have anyone encounter this nice line on paypal settings page?

You haven't created any settings for making small purchases (less than 100 CZK) that don't require shipping.

I can't realy find a solution how to set micropayments on paypal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1) You can enable it on your account here:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/digital-goods

**WARNING** Once you enable it, it affects **ALL** payments coming into your account at a rate of 5% + $0.05

2) You can use Digital Goods checkout: (Which self adjusts the fee depending on the price, on a per-item basis)

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG

**Update 2015**
The marketing pages change all the time, so it's hard to keep these links up  to date. Basically do a google search for `PayPal MicroPayments` and the first few hits will have instructions on how to enable.

The process doesn't change that often:

```
Log in to your PayPal account.
Click Profile at the top of the page.
Click My settings.
Click Update in the My checkout settings.
Select the payment preference you wish to use.
Click Update settings.
Click Yes to update your settings.
```

Comment: I already enabled it in paypal-labs. Their Check status button tells me it is activated. But this warning in settings page is still here. Is it mandatory to implement ExpressCheckout with this overlays and lightboxes? For me it is better to implement classical ExpressCheckout.

Comment: paypal-labs link is broken :(

Comment: It's called digital goods now. Updated the link. You owe me an upvote :P

Comment: for me all links are broken : (
specially this one https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/digital-goods

Comment: Updated answer.  Google is your friend.

Comment: After going through steps from the process i get:
"You haven't created any settings for making small purchases (less than 20,00 PLN) that don't require shipping." - very meaningful sentance, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **you are not allowed to enable micro payments anymore**, as of 1st January 2017

If you did enable micro payments in the past, **it will remain active**.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/digital-goods/

```
Note: Express Checkout Digital Goods is no longer available for new integrations. 
This feature remains available for merchant accounts that already have Express Checkout Digital Goods enabled.
```